# Read an external HTML file/website or call Web Service from Google Earth Engine using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, web-service, http

I need to call either an HTML page from the web based tool or be able to comunicate with a web service. I tried using the function `XMLHttpRequest()`. However, the console prints the error `"XMLHttpRequest" is not defined in this scope`. Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

The reason for the mentioned process is because I need to get the contents from a weather station's webpage. From this webpage, there are a few tables I would process to get daily values of some things I can't get from Earth Engine's list of satellites.

I found a couple of links which both go over what I'm trying to do in JavaScript, JQuery, and AJAX. However, from my testing, none of the methods worked in Earth Engine.

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/here-is-the-most-popular-ways-to-make-an-http-request-in-javascript-954ce8c95aaa/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535055/load-html-file-contents-to-div-without-the-use-of-iframes/3535126

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using the Earth Engine Code Editor (https://code.earthengine.google.com/)? There you're working inside a sandbox, with limitations on what you can do. You don't have access to `XMLHttpRequest`, amongst several other JavaScript features.

If you need these features, you'll have to build a custom app (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/app_engine_intro), not necessarily using Google App Engine like the docs prescribes though.